# Using Pandas, Matplotlib, or Seaborn, how can I create a stacked and categorized Bar Chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have done extensive searching, and while other questions/answers get me *part of the way there*, none of them directly address my problem of creating a **categorized** and **stacked** barplot.

What gets me part of the way there:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="Step",y="Time",data=df_test,kind="bar")
for ax in g.axes.flat[1:]:
    sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_title())
    ax.set_title('')
    ax.margins(x=0.03)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: Expected / Desired Result]

[image: Actual Result]

How can I have the barplot ***not repeat the individual steps for each category*** then label the categories below the x-axis labels (steps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the extensive x-axis, you need to set `sharex=False`.  Also, make sure the `'Step'` column is of string type (not `pd.Categorical` as this will cause ticks for all categories in each subplot).

To create the overall bars, you could loop through the generated bars, calculate their total height, and the overall position.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Step': [f'Step{i + 1}' for i in range(6)],
                        'Time': [5, 6, 7, 5, 10, 3],
                        'Process': [f'Process{i // 2 + 1}' for i in range(6)]})

g = sns.catplot(x='Step', y='Time', data=df_test, col='Process', kind='bar', width=0.9,
                hue='Process', dodge=False, palette=['dodgerblue', 'yellow', 'chartreuse'], saturation=0.90,
                sharex=False, sharey=True, height=4, aspect=0.7)
for ax in g.axes.flat[1:]:
    sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True)
for process, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
    bars = [b for b in ax.patches if type(b) == matplotlib.patches.Rectangle and not np.isnan(b.get_height())]
    if len(bars) > 0:
        sum_heights = sum(b.get_height() for b in bars)
        overall_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy=(bars[0].get_x() - 0.05, 0),
                                     width=bars[-1].get_x() - bars[0].get_x() + bars[-1].get_width() + 0.10,
                                     height=sum_heights,
                                     color=bars[0].get_facecolor(), alpha=0.3)
        ax.add_patch(overall_rect)
    ax.set_xlabel(process)
    ax.set_title('')
    ax.margins(x=0.03)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)
    ax.autoscale_view() # update x and y limits to include new rectangle
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn bar plot with overall sums per subplot]

PS: Aligning the xlabels when the rotated x tick labels have different lengths, doesn't seem to be simple.  I tried replacing the xlabel with a text using axes coordinates (`0.5` is the fixed horizontal center, `-0.6` needs to be adjusted to your data):

```py
    # ax.set_xlabel(process)
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.text(0.5, -0.6, process, transform=ax.transAxes, ha='center', va='center')
```

Comment: As an extension to the question, how can I keep the "Process 1", "Process 2" etc. category labels all at the same y-height? If my "Step 1", "Step 2" etc. labels are different lengths then the category labels are not at the same y-height